# ios Xtify push api 415 status code when trying to send a payload to instant push

Tags: api, push-notification, push, xtify, http-status-code-415

I'm trying to send an payload to Xtify 2.0 push api.

I tried from both my iOS app using this code :

```
- (void)sendPushToXids:(NSMutableArray *)xids {
        ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xtifyPushUrl]];
        req.requestMethod = @"POST";

        [req setPostValue:xAppKey forKey:@"appKey"];
        [req setPostValue:xApiKey forKey:@"apiKey"];
        [req setPostValue:xids forKey:@"xids"];

        NSMutableDictionary *contentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [contentDict setObject:@"This is a message" forKey:@"message"];
        [contentDict setObject:@"default.caf" forKey:@"sound"];

        [req setPostValue:contentDict forKey:@"content"];

        req.delegate = self;
        [req startAsynchronous];
    }
```

where xids is a NSMutableArray with one item.

Also i tried using this code using Firefox plugin REST Client:
Header:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Data:

```
{
    "apiKey": "myapikey",
    "appKey": "myappkey",
    "xids": ["500865a987242167c69b4e6c"], 
    "content": {
        "subject": "Greetings Earthlings",
        "message": "Take me to your leader"
    }
}
```

(where my "myapikey" and "myappkey" are replaced with my app keys)

with method POST and url "http://api.xtify.com/2.0/push"

In both cases Xtify responds with :

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

type Status report

message Unsupported Media Type

description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, i was missing the content-type header. But now i get 400 authorization needed. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message means your API key is not correct or expired. Make sure to create an advanced key in the Xtify console.